# Jquery open same parent page in popup does not works

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have one page called ParentPage and in that I open one jquery modal popup called ChildPage. Now in ChildPage we are using jquery tabs which can open multiple pages in ChildPage.

So now in that jquery tab we have one link which opens actually the same page which was my ParentPage from where I had opened modal popup.

Now issue is that if I opened same page in popup it actually conflicts with parent page because both pages have same elements with same ids and it sets data into parent page instead of child page.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: And you're not using iFrames, but just loading the same page into a modal in the same page etc ?

Comment: Then use iFrame, as you can't just load the same page inside itself by sticking the same HTML in an element etc.

Comment: I have already thought that but it arises some other issues, so I can't use it. Is there any other solution then iframe?

Comment: Create a different page, let it have same number of components as Parent Page and open that new page.

Comment: I think you're working in RCM!!! ;)

Comment: Jaikart. Coding the same thing twice is not a good idea.